# How can I get Bus channel information in asammdf?

Tags: python, can-bus, mdf, asammdf

I'm trying to get information from .mdf files using Python.
There are same signal name with diffrent Bus channel. (ECU1 ~ ECU4)

[image: For example, Bus channel 2]

So, I have to separate singals according to bus channel.
Is it possible to do that?

Sincerely, I need help.
Thanks.

Comment: We can't really help you unless we see how you are accessing the files.  Why don't you show us the code you have, and what you're currently printing?